# How to create common.css file and use postcss only?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, postcss

This is my current webpack config – https://gist.github.com/lavezzi1/1179d91c584c0b0a7544c862c8bb07ca

As you can see I do multipage app and faced with a few problems.

1. I want to compile 2 files for each page: **common.css** (css file with common styles)  and **index.css** (for example css file with individual styles for index page). How I can do that? I tried CommonChunks plugin but it generates only common.js file, not css. Now I found a workaround how to make it, I just import main.css file directly in entry js file of the each page. But it makes another problem, which describes below;
2. I want to use postcss without any preprocessors. Is it possible? When I import main.css directly in js file postcss plugin doesn't work (code doesn't compile) I tested postcss-nested plugin which works just fine inside of *.vue file. How to fix that?

I am very stuck with it. I hope you help. Thanks!

Comment: So your workflow would be `many.css->one.css-(postcss)->processed.ccs`? And then you want to ship that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `!postcss-loader` after `!css-loader`?

The net result would be:

```
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader','css-loader!postcss-loader?sourceMap!sass-loader')
```